# What is the correct word order in the included sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, word-order

As a non-native speaker I’m struggling with how to order the clauses in the following sentence:

1. Because I, as a graduate of a vocational college and as someone who has already successfully absolved an internship, have a range of experience to offer.
2. Because as a graduate of a vocational college and as someone who has already successfully absolved an internship, I have a range of experience to offer.

Is either or both of these two sentences grammatical and natural-sounding in English? If both are ok, would one be preferred over the other? Would some other ordering than given here be better, and if so, why?

Comment: "absolved" seems an odd choice of word in this case

Comment: Get rid of the _as_'s. And (2) is clearer than (1).

Comment: Your sentences are dependent clauses and hence fragments by some definitions. Your first sentence separates the subject "I" by a long way from its verb "have". This makes it in my opinion the less preferable version.

Comment: "Because" is a preposition, so they are not clauses but preposition phrases.

Comment: @BillJ. Yes, the CGEL analyses "because" as a preposition. However, I suspect that a large majority of teaching and learning materials for non-native speakers continue to categorise "because" as a (subordinating) "conjunction".

Comment: Unlike ELL, ELU is not aimed at N-Ns. [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/because)

Comment: @BillJ.  The OP is a non-native speaker who may not be familiar with the CGEL's analysis and terminology. Aarts in _Oxford Modern English Grammar_ calls "_because_" a "_conjunctive preposition_". Quirk in the _Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language_ calls _"because"_ a "_conjunction_". I think it is helpful to state the source of the terminology one is using.

Comment: Aarts acknowledges that it is essentially a prep, and Quirk is simply wrong.

Comment: @BillJ. There's an interesting discussion to be had on who gets to decide which classification is "right" and which is "wrong". In my experience most English learners are much more concerned with correct usage than classification of the various language constituents. All I am prepared to say on classification is something like "_CGEL's classification of 'because' as a preposition is the most convincing of the analyses I have read._"

Answer (score 3):

Initial ***because*** is syntactically irrelevant to the issue under consideration here, so I'll pretend it doesn't exist (at least then the two texts look more like "sentences").

The first example is stylistically very poor, because the syntactically *optional* adverbial clause *(**as a graduate ... internship**)* is so long that it's unreasonable to expect the reader to remember the initial subject *(**I...**)* until he finally reaches the associated verb *(**...have** a range of experience)*.

OP's *second* suggestion really does benefit from the comma[s]...

> 2a: *As a graduate of a vocational college [,] and as someone who has already successfully absolved an internship, I have a range of experience to offer.*

...but *feasibly* that comma could be omitted if we change the sequence...

> 3: *I have a range of experience to offer [,] as a graduate of a vocational college [,] and as someone who has already successfully absolved an internship.*

Personally, I would either include *both* or *neither* of the commas above, but that's essentially a stylistic choice.

---

I don't recognise the usage *to **absolve** an internship*, but that's another question entirely.

Comment: I suspect the OP is German, The German word _absolvieren_ means to complete a course of study.

Comment: @Shoe Somehow along the centuries German deviated from Latin's sense famously seen in *Ego te absolvo a peccatis tuis*, which is the only dominant sense in English. These sorts of things happen from time to time in one language but not in another.

Comment: @tchrist: Before I started writing my answer (and thus before seeing Shoe's comment) I'd intended to edit my own guess (which was obviously **completed** anyway) into the Question (in brackets with a question mark). But as things have turned out, that *particular* "irrelevant" word has generated far more attention here than the "syntactically disastrous" inclusion of ***because*** in OP's example text.

Comment: @tchrist. Thanks for the reminder of the countless hours of my youth spent in bored contemplation of the stations of the cross.

Answer (score 3):

The conjunction "and" coordinates two prepositional phrases: "as a graduate of a vocational college" and "as someone who has already successfully absolved an internship". Because those are unnecessary modifiers, let's remove them:

> Because I have a range of experience to offer.

This is a subordinate clause and thus does not constitute a complete sentence, at least in the traditional sense. You can fix the problem simply by deleting "because".

As noted in another answer, sentence 1 separates the sentence's subject and verb with a lengthy phrase, so sentence 2 is probably better stylistically.

As also noted in that other answer, "absolved" is not the correct word here.

Comment: Interestingly, CGEL calls "because" a preposition. See Geoff Pullum's convincing explanation here [link](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=9494)